# Processing CampaignMember object without hitting governor limits

Tags: governorlimits, contact, loop, campaign-member, cpulimit

Campaign is used to create parent campaign which is assigned to each term. Each parent gets set of child campaigns with parentId=null (that's how we distinguish between parent and child campaigns)

CampaignMember is used to store relationship between contact, campaign and attendance status of the contact for the campaign. CampaignMember is the only object which has attendance status. parent campaign uses Paid or UnPaid, and the rest are used for child campaigns.

```
    Campaign: {
      Id: 'Id',
      Name: 'String',
      ParentId: null || CampaignId of a parent
      StartDate: 'Date', //not DateTime
    }
    Contact: {
      Id: 'Id',
      FirstName: 'String',
      LastName: 'String',
      SchooldId: 'schoolId unique to each person'
    }

    CampaignMember: {
      Id: 'Id',
      CampaignId: 'Id from Campaign',
      ContactId: 'Id from Contact',
      Attendance__c: 'String one of below
                      Paid||UnPaid||NoShow||Void||Attended||Registered'
    }
```

Contact with Campaigns look like this:

```
Contact
Kate Smith

Addresses
A-12345

Campaign History
     Campaign Name   Start Date     Type     Attendance
     Spring 2019     1/1/2019       Test     Paid
     session 1       3/25/2019      Test     Void
     session 2       4/15/2019      Test     No Show
```

**Problem**:

I am trying to create a script where it looks at all campaignMember records and check for "Paid" status. If 'Paid' CampaignMember is found, I need to find associated child campaignMember from the campaignMember object, and get the latest campaignMember (session 2 would be the latest) status to see if I can transfer the Paid status to the next period or not.

However, since campaignMember object contains both parent and child campaigns and the only way for me to check which campaignMember is the latest is to query a list of campaignMembers by contactId, and sort that by looking at the mapped/hashed campaign startDate.

I keep hitting governor limits, and don't know what I can do to solve this problem.

As of today, for current parent period, I have 1400 Paid 85 Unpaid so at least I would need to be able to process around 1500 records at the end of this month.

**EDIT**

```
public static void getCampaignMembers() {
campaignMembers = [
  SELECT Id, CampaignId, ContactId, Attendance__c
  FROM CampaignMember
  WHERE (CampaignId = :currentParentCampaignId AND Attendance__c = 
         'Paid') OR CampaignId IN :currentChildCampaignIDs];
}

public static void createCampaignAndContactMap() {
   for (CampaignMember campaigMember : campaignMembers) {
     if (unPaidContactMap.containsKey(campaigMember.ContactId) == false) 
     {

      if(contactIdCampaignMemberMap.containsKey(campaigMember.ContactId) 
            == true) 
       {
         List<CampaignMember> currentListOfCM = 
             contactIdCampaignMemberMap.get(campaigMember.ContactId);
             currentListOfCM.add(campaigMember);
       } else {
         List<CampaignMember> campMemberList = new List<CampaignMember> 
                              ();
         campMemberList.add(campaigMember);
         contactIdCampaignMemberMap.put(campaigMember.ContactId, 
                                                  campMemberList);
       }
     }
   }
 }

 public static void getTheLatestCampaignMemberToCheck() {
   CampaignMember latestCampaignMemberToCheck = new CampaignMember();

   for (Id contactIdKey : contactIdCampaignMemberMap.keySet()) 
   {
     List<CampaignMember> listOfCampaignMembers = 
                        contactIdCampaignMemberMap.get(contactIdKey);

     List<Campaign> sortableCampaigns = new List<Campaign>();
    for (CampaignMember cm : listOfCampaignMembers) 
    {
      sortableCampaigns.add(
        currentChildCampaignSortableByStartDateMap.get(cm.CampaignId));
    }

    // sorts in ASC order - there is no DESC order sort...
    sortableCampaigns.sort();
    Integer lastItemIndex = sortableCampaigns.size() - 1;
    Campaign latestCampaign = sortableCampaigns.get(lastItemIndex);

    for (CampaignMember campaignMember : listOfCampaignMembers) 
    {
      if (campaignMember.CampaignId == latestCampaign.Id) 
      {
        latestCampaignMemberToCheck = campaignMember;
        break;
      }
    }
     checkLatestCampaignMember(latestCampaignMemberToCheck, 
                        listOfCampaignMembers);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Can you show us your code that you are using which is hitting a limit? Also which limit are you exceeding?

Comment: I was creating 1500 contact records in my unit tests and that hit CPU limit, so I am assuming that me looping through campaignMember which is 1500+ records would fail. I'm editing my question to include that part of code. Thank you!